# Java cannot load shared object library with JNI on OSX

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use JNI to join Java and C in the simplest way on my friend's 64-bit OSX and I'm getting this error. Here's everything involved:

test.java

```
public class test {

    static {System.loadLibrary ("test");}

    native void aaa ();

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new test ();
    }

    public test () {
        aaa ();
    }
}
```

test.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class test */

#ifndef _Included_test
#define _Included_test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     test
 * Method:    aaa
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_aaa
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "test.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_aaa
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf ("AWD");
}
```

makefile

```
CC          =   gcc
CFLAGS      =   -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g3

default :
    javac test.java
    javah -jni test
    gcc -c test.c -o test.o -I${HOME}/../../System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/
    gcc -shared -Wl,-install_name,libtest.so -o libtest.so test.o
```

I had to use -install_name instead of -soname because I read that OSX doesn't have -soname like Linux.

Then I do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
java test
```

and I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at test.<clinit>(test.java:2)
```

So I really don't know what the problem is. I copied all the files onto Linux and switched -install_name to -soname and changed the paths to jni.h and it works just fine.

Comment: On OSX it's `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X, JNI looks for libraries with the extension `.jnilib`, or with the standard OS X shared library extension of `.dylib`.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/05-CoreJavaAPIs/CoreJavaAPIs.html

Comment: At one point - Java 1.4, IIRC - only `.jnilib` was used, so if backcompat with very old runtimes is required, that is to be recommended.  But regardless, `.so` is never correct.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - cheers. I've found a better source and updated with that. Apple seem to think it happened since OS X 10.5, but that is probably just due to the VM that it shipped with.